# Train NN for balanced accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to get a NN (a CNN, to be precise) to predict labels on hugely imbalanced data, i.e. some classes are much bigger than others. I want to optimize the balanced accuracy. So I give the class weight to the model which I compute like so:

```
classes = np.unique(y_ord)
class_weight = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=classes, y=y_ord)
class_weight = {k: v for k, v in zip(classes, class_weight)}  # make class_weight a dict
```

Now, I train my model using the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss. However, while the loss decreases, accuracy does not improve. I've read in several blog posts the (possible) reason why: The loss is continuous, while the accuracy is either 0 or 1. However, I've failed to find a way to deal with this. This does not happen when I do not use the weights, so I guess it must have something to do with these.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the before/after individual classes' accuracy? Did you try under-sampling?